# Is it possible to use a .Net5 (core) library from a .Net Framework app?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-4.0, .net-5

I've been trying to determine if I can call a .Net5 library/DLL from .Net Framework4.x code. There seems to be a number of articles about using .Net Standard but now that things are suppose to be consolidated into .Net 5 I'm not sure if/how things have changed. Any good references or articles out there? Can I even access a .Net5 Library from a framework app?

Comment: short answer: no. [see the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/net-standard) for compatibility. i've also researched this a few weeks back and found no solution.

Comment: The short answer is: no.

Comment: In a full framework project you can depend on .NET Standard 2 or lower library, not .NET 5.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five)

You mentioned:

> now that things are suppose to be consolidated into .Net 5

Not really true, as you can see in the documentation:

> .NET 5.0 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1. We named this new release .NET 5.0 instead of .NET Core 4.0 for two reasons:
>
> We skipped version numbers 4.x to avoid confusion with .NET Framework 4.x.
>
> **We dropped "Core" from the name to emphasize that this is the main implementation of .NET going forward.** .NET 5.0 supports more types of apps and more platforms than .NET Core or .NET Framework.

So it's still net core in all but name. You still need to use .net standard to support both platforms. Check te comments for compatibility.

This might also be interesting to you: [choosing-core-framework-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server)